# How to create Date(now) within Vue.js to use in a computed property?

Tags: date, vue.js, computed-properties

I have an array of calendar events with a pre-formatted date: **20190517T010000Z**.

I need to filter the array based upon the following:

1) Future Events (any events occurring greater than `NOW`)

2) Past Events (any events that occurred less than `NOW`)

3) New Events created within the past 7 days (`NOW` - 7 days)

I have an example hardcoded below - but need `NOW` to be dynamic and based upon the user's system time.  I can't figure out how to get `NOW` in the same format as the datetime format I'm getting in the my array.  Also, I don't know where in my code it should reside (within a separate JS file or within the Vue component)?

Once I have it working within the component listed below, it will be moved to a VUEX Getter.

```
<template>
    <div class="text-left m-4 p-4">
        <div>
            Total Number Events: {{ allEvents.length }}
        </div>
        <div>
            Events Created In Last 7 Days: {{ createdEvents }}
        </div>
        <div>
            Future Events: {{ futureEvents }}
        </div>
        <div>
            Past Events: {{ pastEvents }}
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex'

export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapState(['allEvents']),

    futureEvents () {
      return this.$store.state.allEvents.filter(allEvents => allEvents.dtstart >= '20190517T010000Z').length
    },

    pastEvents () {
      return this.$store.state.allEvents.filter(allEvents => allEvents.dtstart <= '20190517T235900Z').length
    },

    createdEvents () {
      return this.$store.state.allEvents.filter(
        allEvents => allEvents.created >= '20190511T235900Z' && allEvents.created <= '20190517T235900Z' )
        .length
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

The above code works - but it is hardcoded right now and it needs to be dynamic.  Any thoughts or suggestions would be welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All your date time objects should be persisted as UNIX timestamps (UTC seconds since 1/1/1970). This will allow you to compare times across systems no matter the timezone.

Provided that the events in your Vuex store are stored with `dstart` being a UNIX timestamp, the following snippet should give you the dynamic behaviour you want.

I've created a `now` attribute in the component's data. This gets updated every second, causing the computed properties to refresh.

Additionally, if the `allEvents` property in the Vuex store updates, the computed properties will also refresh.

```
<template>
    <div class="text-left m-4 p-4">
        <div>
            Total Number Events: {{ allEvents.length }}
        </div>
        <div>
            Events Created In Last 7 Days: {{ createdEvents }}
        </div>
        <div>
            Future Events: {{ futureEvents }}
        </div>
        <div>
            Past Events: {{ pastEvents }}
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import { mapState } from 'vuex'
    export default {
        data () {
            return {
                now: new Date().getUTCSeconds()
            }
        },
        created () {
            this.scheduleUpdateNow();
        },
        methods: {
            updateNow() {
                this.now = new Date().getUTCSeconds();
                this.scheduleUpdateNow();
            },
            scheduleUpdateNow() {
                setTimeout(this.updateNow, 1000);
            }
        },
        computed: {
            ...mapState(['allEvents']),

            futureEvents () {
                return this.$store.state.allEvents.filter(allEvents => allEvents.dtstart > this.now).length
            },

            pastEvents () {
                return this.$store.state.allEvents.filter(allEvents => allEvents.dtstart <= this.now).length
            },

            createdEvents () {
                return this.$store.state.allEvents.filter(
                    allEvents => allEvents.created >= this.now && allEvents.created <= this.now).length
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: P.S. I'm not sure what your last computed function `createdEvents` is doing - I've left the logic "as-is". It appears to find all events created now - but this is very unlikely to match anything as "now" is very specific!

Comment: thanks for the answer ...  The `createdEvents` is to filter for Events created between two dates - with the "end" date being NOW and going back 7 days.  Once I have a NOW date, making the calc shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: Appreciate this ... I didn't know exactly where to put the NOW

Comment: Datetime is coming preformatted via a calendaring system as `YYYYMMDDTHHMMSSZ` ... where would reformat/reshape the incoming datetime?

Comment: Perhaps as you're receiving the events from the calendaring system, parse the string to a Date object then store the dates as a UNIX timestamp.